# Why is this validation rule not firing?

Tags: validation-rule

```
 AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(Evaluation_Stage__c, 'Technical Win'), 
    ISBLANK(Actual_Number_of_IP_s_in_POC__c), 
    ISBLANK(Date_of_POC_Planning_Meeting__c), 
    ISBLANK(TEXT( POC_Type__c)), 
    ISBLANK(POC_For_of_Endpoints__c), 
    ISBLANK(Customer_Technical_Lead_Name__c), 
    ISBLANK(TEXT(X802_1x__c)), 
    ISBLANK( Confirmed_Installation_Date__c), 
    ISBLANK(Type_of_Product__c), 
    ISBLANK(Use_Cases__c ), 
    ISBLANK(Policies__c), 
    ISBLANK(Closing_Meeting_Date__c), 
    ISBLANK(Estimated_Number_of_IOT_s_in_Producton__c), 
    ISBLANK(Est_Number_of_User_Endpoints_in_Prod__c) 
)
```

It is active, too. Thanks!

Comment: The activation rule would fire only when all the 13 fields are blank. Are you sure they are not blank on the records you are testing? I think you want to user OR instead of AND.

Comment: You will get much better feedback if you explain what you are trying to achieve (not just what you tried).